# What is the electric potential at the point charge, at the source of field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential-energy, singularities, coulombs-law

$$V(r)=k_eq/r$$

What is the electric potential when the test charge is placed very very close to the source charge, ie when $r=0$? Is it infinity?

Comment: See [answers](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/283956/how-to-calculate-the-sound-pressure-at-a-given-distance-of-a-point-source) for a similar question regarding potential in $1/r$.

Comment: So, what if the charge is an electron? What is the potential very close to the surface of the electron?

Comment: In classical physics, assuming a point charge, the potential $\to \infty$ when $r \to0$.

Comment: But that is physically impossible, right? Would you please explain the concept behind the argument and please do look at @AHB 's answer.

Comment: Yes, a point charge in classical physics is physically impossible, it is only a model which is very convenient to use when your are "far" from the source. You may want to use other models if you want to get closer, and you may finally have to enter QM.

Comment: @Allen My argument was correct per se. The assumptions were wrong. The thing I didn't notice was that Physics is built according to nature behavior. If we get too close to an electron for example, then we have entered QED. In which the motion of electron isn't completely determined. We only know where the electron is the most probable to be.

Comment: so classical mechanics will be no more applicable. Thanks @AHB

Comment: @Allen visit here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, why don't you just input actual values and see what happens?

You get the electric field by taking negative potential gradient and as you can see, it varies inversely with square of distance. So if the distance changes from 1m to 10^-3 m then the force will be 10^6 times greater. You see where I am going with this? It becomes stronger and stronger and hence you have to do more and more work. Thus the potential will approach infinity.